# Argument IndexController not a function, got undefined: when running karma test

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Here is my test file for testing the IndexController

```
//modules/application/tests/spec/controllers/IndexController.js

'use strict';    
(function() {
    describe('Application IndexController', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            module('HtEwa');
            module('HtEwa.Application');
        });

        var scope, IndexController;

        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            IndexController = $controller('IndexController', {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));

        it('should expose global scope', function() {
            expect(scope.global).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
})();
```

I have seen other answers but it is not working for me. And I have the files included in my karma.conf.js is:

```
files:_.flatten(_.values(assets.core.js)).concat([
        'modules/*/*.js',
        'modules/*/*/*.js',
        'modules/*/tests/spec/*/*.js'
    ]);
```

I have `HtEwa` and `HtEwa.Application` module. Under the `HtEwa.Application` there is IndexController.

```
//modules/application/controllers/IndexController.js
    'use strict';
angular.module('HtEwa.Application').controller('IndexController', ['$scope', 'Global',
    function($scope, Global) {
        $scope.global = Global;    
    }
]);
```

I guess that my IndexController file is not included, but I have included `modules/*/*/*.js` in my `karma.conf.js` and that's where the IndexController is.Or Am I missing anything?

Edit:
And the karma `--log-level debug` shows that all files that are needed is served.
Here are the included files that i watched from chrome

```
 <!-- Dynamically replaced with <script> tags -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/modules/application/application.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/modules/application/controllers/FooterController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/modules/application/controllers/HeaderController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/modules/application/controllers/IndexController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/modules/application/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/modules/application/routes/ApplicationRoutes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/modules/application/services/Global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/modules/application/services/HTTPInterceptor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/modules/application/tests/spec/controllers/IndexController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/modules/users/controllers/UserController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/modules/users/routes/Auth.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/modules/users/services/UserService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/modules/users/tests/spec/controllers/UserController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/modules/users/users.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.__karma__.loaded();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this instead:

```
files:_.flatten(_.values(assets.core.js)).concat([
    'modules/**/*.js'
]);
```

Notice the use of two `*`. Read the File Pattern example in the **[karma configuration documentation](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html)**.

Wherein the examples are:

- `**/*.js`: All files with a "js" extension in all subdirectories
- `**/!(jquery).js`: Same as previous, but excludes "jquery.js"
- `**/(foo|bar).js`: In all subdirectories, all "foo.js" or "bar.js" files

Comment: I have added that now it shows another error: `  Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'HtEwa.Users' is not available! You either mis
spelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure tha
t you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Comment: and i have defined that module in modules/users/users.js

Comment: It is not working this way too. I have followed the mean.io structure and in `karma.conf.js` file of sample mean app i used the above pattern and it didn't work.